# How do I pass a function as a parameter to another function?

Tags: php, closures, php-5.3, lambda

I have a list of functions `a()`, `b()`, `c()`
I have a `main()` function.

Depending on case, I need to pass a different function to main() to use.
In javascript it would be:

```
var a = function(){}
var b = function(){}
var c = function(){}

var func = (some logic) a, b or c;

main(func);
```

How do I do that in php5.3?
I am trying to avoid using

```
$func_name = "a";
main($func_name){
   $func_name();
}
```

Or may be it is the best way, and I should not use closures of any type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same idea in PHP 5.3, as you can create [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$sayHello = function($var)
{
    echo "Hello ", $var;
};

// Logic here to determine what $func is set to
$func = $sayHello;    

function callCustom($function)
{
    if(!is_callback($function))
    {
        // throw exception
    }
    $function("World");
}

callCustom($func);  // Hello World
```

Comment: is there a way to type hint this? `function xxx(func $function){}`

Comment: @ItayMoav:  You can't type hint callbacks, but you can add a condition that will detect if the parameter is not a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = function(){};
$b = function(){};
$c = function(){};

switch (rand(0, 2)) {
    case 0: $func = $a; break;
    case 1: $func = $b; break;
    case 2: $func = $c; break;
}

var_dump($func);
```

You can see a working example here http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ut5yGQ

Note: I used `var_dump` instead of `main` as `main` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, anything that is "callable" ([`is_callable`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/is_callable)) can be called (invoked). The manual often names these parameters as [*Callback*, a pseudo-type in PHP<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php).

You can use any of the different callbacks and pass them as a function parameter:

```
function main($callback)
{
    call_user_func($callback);
}
```

Then your function will work with any valid PHP callback.

Next to that, functions can be called with variables, some examples:

*Variable Function Call:*

```
  function name() {};
  $function = 'name'; # function name as string
  $function(); # invoke
```

*Anonymous Function as Variable Function Call:*

```
  $function = function() {}; # define function
  $function(); # invoke
```

See as well [Variable Functions<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).